# Java SWING - How to put my functionality under my tabs?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, tabs

At the Moment I am coding my GUI, but my programm functionality flows under my tabs.

Example:

[image]

Does anybody has an idea how to fix that?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (rather than 4K lines in 20 classes of 'your code').    It does not *look* to be the problem, but still, ensure the code does not mix Swing with AWT components.

Comment: here it is -> http://pasteit.com/17246

Comment: 1) To notify someone of a comment, add @PersonName as a prefix.  You're just lucky I checked back on this.  2) That code does not compile, so could not have produced a screen-shot, let alone be the code you are using to see the problem.  Also, is the 3rd party logger really necessary for demonstrating the problem?  If not, it should not be in an SSCCE.

Comment: thx for having a look at my code!!! here is my "compilable" version: http://pasteit.com/17247 I hope that i have now shown my problem clear enough...

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Layout is broken.
2. Try to split up component-parts (tabs and the panel content below tabs).
3. Add only these parts and see whether the layout of those particular components is OK.
4. Put everything you have into a **scrollable** would help you to analyse the problem and see the actual required size of your components.
5. Try to avoid using prefferedSize/minSize/maxSize in your code, it was not meant to layout your stuff.